# To Whom It May Concern, what's the best way to address a group?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, email

I write emails to groups of individuals from time to time, and when I don't/can't address anyone in particular, I will begin the letter with

> To Whom It May Concern,

Is this the best way to equally address a group of people, in a professional setting?

Comment: It depends greatly on context.  This is fine, but could potentially be better.  Who are these *groups of individuals* you are emailing?

Comment: what about nothing? the list of recipients gives a list of people the email is addressed to

Comment: @dotsamuelswan various groups, mostly that work at the same company, but I have no dealings with day to day.

Comment: For internal emails, it's really going to boil down to your company's culture.  As @SeanCheshire suggested, *nothing* may be perfectly acceptable.  If the content you're sending affects some, but not all of the people receiving the email, *to whom it may concern* probably makes the most sense.  You may also consider something like "Dear Associates,".

Comment: Of course, emails don't have steadfast rules for composition. You may also consider popping over to the Workplace Stack Exchange site with this question. http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is also a question of formality. For an email - especially internally - and double especially in the US - I would never start an email with "To whom it may concern". You could start the email with "Hi,", "Hi all," or just be done with it and launch straight into the body of the email itself and let the subject of the email introduce it.

Comment: Related: [#2112](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/dear-sir-or-madam-versus-to-whom-it-may-concern), and, more recently, [#112206](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112206/which-form-of-address-in-motivation-letter).

Comment: I will **begin** the letter, or, I will **being** the letter?

Comment: +matt, I am in the US, and no professional letters I have seen begins with "Hi" or "Hi All" and in the case of a general and respected audience, always begins with "To whom it may concern".

Comment: @BlessedGeek: A typo that obvious should just be fixed, don't you think?

Comment: Yes +JR. Unfortunately, unless I am the author, this bletchy site won't me fix it unless it is a significant fix of more than 10 (15,25?) chars.

Comment: @Matt. In the UK also, I would NEVER start an email (nor anything else) with "To whom it may concern" - it sounds very officious, outdated, impersonal, and UNprofessional. I agree with your other suggestions.

Comment: The most common way I see for addressing a group via email is "Hi all" if they are all known to you and "Dear all" if it is to be more formal.

Comment: Related (capitalization): https://english.stackexchange.com/q/72406/216106

Answer (score 2):

The very very formal method seems to be "Sir(s) or Madam(s)," depending on whether you the number&gender of the recipients or not.